# Send data from Lightning component to visualforce page without window.postmessage

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning-events, spring19

I am using window.postmessage() to send data from lightning component to visualforce page as given in below link.

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/01/lightning-visualforce-communication.html

For some reason window.postmessage() in not working in Microsoft edge after spring'19 release.
Is there any other way to communicate between independent lightning component and visualforce page without window.postmessage()?

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: @codeyinthecloud When I used post message, I added Vf page as Iframe and then using that I was sending message to VF page. Suppose if I use dispatchEvent in lightning component, how a visualforce page will listen to that event as vf and lightning components are in different container?

Comment: Has any one achieved this using any other way?

Answer (score 1):

you can try lightning message service, this is a new feature. http://www.webuildsf.cloud/salesforce-crm/an-example-to-communicate-between-lightning-web-components-and-visualforce-pages/

Comment: yes, earlier when i posted this question this feature was not available.